# How can I merge images from two folders into a together side-by-side with imagemagick?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I have two folders, `A and B`, with image files that have corresponding names.

For example, each contain files labelled `01.png, 02.png, 03.png, etc`.

How can I *merge* the corresponding files such that I have a third `folder C` that contains all merged photos so that both of the originals are side by side.

I am on `Linux`, if that changes anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not near a computer to thoroughly test, but this seems easiest to me:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Goto directory A
cd A

# For each file "f" in A
for f in *.png; do
    # Append corresponding file from B and write to AB
    convert "$f" ../B/"$f" +append ../AB/"$f"
done
```

---

Or use **GNU Parallel** and do them all at once!

```
cd A
parallel convert {} ../B/{} +append AB/{} ::: *.png
```

Comment: Mark, much simpler than my answer! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using ImageMagick version 6, if your images are all the same dimensions, and if your system memory can handle reading all the input images into a single command, you can do that with a command like this...

```
convert FolderA/*.jpg -set filename:f "%[f]" \
   -set option:distort:viewport %[fx:w*2] -distort SRT 0 null: \
   FolderB/*.jpg -gravity east -layers composite FolderC/"%[filename:f]"
```

That starts by reading in all the images from FolderA and extending their viewport to double their width to the right.

Then it adds the special built-in "null:" to separate the lists of images before reading in the second list. Then it reads in all the images from FolderB.

Then after setting the gravity to "east", it composites each image from FolderB over the extended right half of each corresponding image from FolderA. That creates the effect of appending the images side by side.

The command sets a variable at the beginning to hold the filenames of the first list of input files, then uses those as the names of the output files and writes them to FolderC.

If you're using ImageMagick version 7, use the command "magick" instead of "convert".

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with some bash scripting code. Assume you have two folders A and B with the corresponding image names in them. Also you have an empty folder AB to hold the results. Then using ImageMagick with the bash looping code, you can do something like this:

```
Collect the names of all the files in folder A and put into an array

Collect the names of all the files in folder B and put into an array

Loop over the number of images in the folders

Process them with ImageMagick +append and save to folder AB
```

```
outdir="/Users/fred/desktop/AB"
aArr=(`find /Users/fred/desktop/A -type f -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.png"`)
numA="${#aArr[*]}"
bArr=(`find /Users/fred/desktop/B -type f -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.png"`)
numB="${#bArr[*]}"
if [ $numA -eq $numB ]; then
for ((i=0; i<numA; i++)); do
nameA=`basename "${aArr[$i]}"`
nameA=`convert "$nameA" -format "%t" info:`
nameB=`basename "${bArr[$i]}"`
nameB=`convert "$nameB" -format "%t" info:`
convert "${aArr[$i]}" "${aArr[$i]}" +append ${outdir}/${nameA}_${nameB}.jpg
done
fi
```