# Stitch series of photos from two directories using PIL

Tags: python, loops, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to stitch a series of images together using the Python Imaging Library. However, the images I want to stitch together are contained in two separate directories. Is `PIL` able to stitch images under this condition?

I have two series of 10 images stored in two directories - let's call them `D1` and `D2`. I would like to use PIL to stitch `Image 1` from `D1` with Image `1` from `D2`, `Image 2` from `D1` with `Image 2` from `D2`, etc. I have a third directory, `D3`, in which I would like to save the stitched output images.

I thought the correct way to do this would be to use the code snipped provided by user `d3ming` in [this example] ([Stitching Photos together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657383/stitching-photos-together)) and use nested for loops to loop over `D1` and `D2` to provide input images.

Here is the code that I have currently:

```
list_im1 = sorted(glob.glob(in_dir_1+"*"))      #make list of first set of images
list_im2 = sorted(glob.glob(in_dir_2+"*"))      #make list of second set of images

def merge_images(file1, file2):
    """Merge two images into one, displayed side by side
    :param file1: path to first image file
    :param file2: path to second image file
    :return: the merged Image object
    """
    image1 = Image.open(file1)
    image2 = Image.open(file2)

    (width1, height1) = image1.size
    (width2, height2) = image2.size

    result_width = width1 + width2
    result_height = max(height1, height2)

    result = Image.new('RGB', (result_width, result_height))
    result.paste(im=image1, box=(0, 0))
    result.paste(im=image2, box=(width1, 0))
    return result
    merged = merge_images(file1, file2) 
    merged.save(out_dir)

for i in in_dir_1:                          #first loop through D1
    for j in in_dir_2:                      #second loop through D2
        merge_images(i, j)
```

I expected that this code snippet, combined with the nested loop, would run through `in_dir_1 (D1)`, search through the image with the same position in `in_dir_2 (D2)`, and return me a series of 10 stitched images in `out_dir (D3)`. However, my code is not returning any output images at all.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are not saving your result `merge_images(i, j)`

Comment: Hmm, but within the function I have a line that saves my result. Should that not work for when I call the function later?

Comment: yes, but that line will never be executed as it is after return statement

Comment: The hard part of stitching is not putting the images together, it's aligning them and evening out the tilt and exposure. You're not likely to be happy with the results from this program even once it works.

Comment: You can do them all in parallel in one line of shell without writing any code... https://stackoverflow.com/a/57298322/2836621

Answer (score 1):

Immediate solution is replacing the `return` statement with `Image.save()`.

```
list_im1 = sorted(glob.glob(in_dir_1+"*"))      #make list of first set of images
list_im2 = sorted(glob.glob(in_dir_2+"*"))      #make list of second set of images

def merge_images(file1, file2):
    """Merge two images into one, displayed side by side
    :param file1: path to first image file
    :param file2: path to second image file
    """
    global ctr
    image1 = Image.open(file1)
    image2 = Image.open(file2)

    (width1, height1) = image1.size
    (width2, height2) = image2.size

    result_width = width1 + width2
    result_height = max(height1, height2)

    result = Image.new('RGB', (result_width, result_height))
    result.paste(im=image1, box=(0, 0))
    result.paste(im=image2, box=(width1, 0))
    result.save(out_dir + str(ctr) + ".png")
    ctr += 1

ctr = 1

for i in in_dir_1:                          #first loop through D1
    for j in in_dir_2:                      #second loop through D2
        merge_images(i, j)
```

I would suggest you to use a dynamic output image file path (`out_dir`), meaning the file path should change with different files. Otherwise same image file would be overwritten over and over as the program goes on.

**EDIT:-**

If you want each image to be saved distinctly, then you can use a counter (just a number to keep track of which image is being processed).

I will be using a global variable which will increment the value of the variable each time a new image has been processed.

Edited the code accordingly.

**EDIT 2:-**

Since, each image has it's pair, therefore the total number of images in both the folder will be same. So you can use `eval()` instead of using a pair of `for` loops in order to get through that issue.

Just replace:-

```
for i in in_dir_1:                          
    for j in in_dir_2:                      
        merge_images(i, j)
```

By:-

```
for i, x in eval(in_dir_1):
    merge_images(in_dir_1[i], in_dir_2[i])
```

Comment: Thank you, this suggestion was very useful, and with your solution I am very close to solving the problem! The closest I have got to a dynamic output filepath is `result.save(out_dir + str(image1) + '.png')` , but this creates 3 image files that are subsequently overwritten. Would you recommend using a for loop within the function to save each file separately?

Comment: @ailsa_naismith Edited the Answer. Now images will be saved as `x.png` (were x is a number)

Comment: Thank you, this helped! The code executed as it should. I realize I now have a different problem, which is that I output 10 x 10 = 100 images, rather than the 10 stitch images I would like. I realize that this is a separate issue caused by my scripting of the last lines, `for i in in_dir_1:    for j in in_dir_2:    merge_images(i, j)`, which correctly creates an image for every i and j list combination. Now have to think of an edit that means only the 1st image of in_dir_1 is stitched to 1st image of in_dir_2, 2nd with 2nd, etc.

Comment: @ailsa_naismith Edited the Answer. See if it works now

Comment: Thanks for your second edit! Using `eval`, I received the following error: `TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object`. However, I was able to produce what I wanted by a very similar code inspired by yours: `for i in range(len(list_im_pic)):
    merge_images(list_im_pic[i], list_im_so2[i])`

Comment: @ailsa_naismith Glad, I could help you out!!